# meaning of って (Dragon maid related)

Tags: particle-って

I was wondering what this って at the beginning of Elma's second line could mean.

Thanks for reading

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like "Oh" in "Oh, what a beautiful morning!" or "Let me see...", it is a word used to directly express an emotion such as surprise, joy, or sadness. The Japanese words "あっ" and "やれやれ" refer to this.
The answer to the question, "って" shows that you are upset.I think the English word for this is "What?".